# Как подставить в FindFirstFile букву?

Tags: c++

```
WCHAR szFileName[255];
GetModuleFileName(NULL, szFileName, 255);// диск 

WIN32_FIND_DATAW wfd;

HANDLE const hFind = FindFirstFileW(L"С:\\report\\*", &wfd); //место д подставить другой

setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != hFind)
{
    do
    {
        std::wcout << &wfd.cFileName[0] << std::endl;
    } while (NULL != FindNextFileW(hFind, &wfd));

    FindClose(hFind);
```

В примере указано что диск С но нужно менять в индивидуальном порядке как можно это сделать чтоб указывало?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вопрос сложный, в том смысле, что сложно понять, в чем состоит ваша проблема. Придется угадывать.

Чтобы заменить диск C на другой, достаточно просто поменять букву в строке. Например, вместо `L"С:\\report\\*"` можно написать `L"D:\\kompot\\*.*"` или `L"Z:\\kefir\\*.*"`.

Строку для поиска можно создавать и динамически. Например

```
WCHAR szPath[] = L"C:\\reports\\*.*";
szPath[0] = L'E';  // На самом деле мы хотим не C:, а E:
. . .
HANDLE hFind = ::FindFirstFile(szPath, ...
```

Или, вот например, вы зачем-то получили путь к текущей программе в `szFileName`, который нигде не используете. Можно на его основе сделать поиск всех текстовых файлов, которые содержатся в каталоге программы.

```
WCHAR szFileName[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileName(NULL, szFileName, MAX_PATH);  // Путь к себе
LPWSTR p = wcsrchr(szFileName, L'\\');          // Найти позицию последней \
*(++p) = L'\0';                                 // Переместить указатель за \ и обрезать строку
wcscat(szFileName, L"*.txt");                   // Хотим найти все файлы .txt в каталоге программы
HANDLE hFind = ::FindFirstFile(szFileName, ...
```

Вот как-то так.

Comment: Только как можно запихнуть в szPath[0] = L'E'; как по другому ("%s", szFileName);

Comment: @Sasha, то. что вы написали, это вообще бессмыслица. Обрывок от какой-то функции форматирования. Разберитесь что такое массив и как с ним работать. Строка С/С++ - это просто массив символов.

Comment: Я не знаю как записать букву с переменной в szPath[0] = L"сюда";

Comment: @Sasha, поясните, пожалуйста, что вы хотите сделать. Я просто не понимаю что означает "записать букву с переменной". Вы хотите вместо символьной константы в правой части использовать символьную переменную или еще что-то? Ну напишите "WCHAR ch = L'E'; szPath[0]=ch;"